# Substracting a lake from my DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, masking

I got a rather small DEM which includes a lake. If I want to calculate the strahler order, flowaccumulation etc. it's calculated wrong. The lake "doesnt exist" in my DEM so I got the values of the bottom of the values. Does somebody know how I can mask the layer so that the values are 0 or n.a. for the area of the lake?

Answer (score 4):

Get a vector (polygon) of the lake(s). Then you have at least two options:

**Option 1: Clip raster by mask layer**

1. `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Extract layer extent` from the DEM layer
2. Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Difference: Input layer = Extent (from step 1), Overlay layer = lakes layer
3. Menu Raster / Extraction / Clip Raster by Mask Layer with the DEM as input and the Difference (from step 2) as overlay (see screenshot):

   [image]

**Option 2: Rasterize lake, multiply in Raster calculator**

1. `Menu Raster / Conversion / Rasterize` with the lakes layeer as input and set `A fixed value to burn` (like 0 in my case) and another value for nodata values - see next screenshot.
2. `Menu Raster / Raster calculator`, multiply the output of raterize with your initial raster to get value of 0 for the lakes.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I forgot to mention that I have the waterbodies layer as a WMS file. So I get the data from a server, therefore I cant really work with it the same way as a normal raster layer. Do you know a way to convert the WMS file to a raster layer? I looked trough google but I didnt find one good way. :/ thanks in advance!

Comment: Right click on  the WMS layer / Export / Save as... and save the desired extent as file to a local folder. However, it depends on the data provider if you are able to download the data. If that is not the case, you should first make sure to have the data ready available. However, this is a completely different question and should be asked separately.